# HQL projection on entities/tables

Tags: hibernate, hql, projection

I have two tables with one to one relationship - Person and House
I tried to use HQL projection like Select p.name, p.dob from Person which returns me the name and dob fine.
However, I dont know how to use projection in HQL if:
1. I want to include the House
2. I want to include only color and year of the House.

i tried `SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName p.house FROM Person p"` but got error with "could not resolve property". What do i need to do to get this right? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple actually by using HQL:

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, h.color, h.year FROM Person p join p.house h
```

This will return a array constain those values.

---

For your second comment, yes, you can has a DTO to do that, e.g.

```
class PersonDTO {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Hourse hourse;
    public PersonDTO(){}

    public PersonDTO(String firstName, String lastName, Hourse hourse) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.hourse = hourse;
    }

    // getter & setter
}
```

then in you HQL, you can return it like 
`SELECT new PersonDTO(p.firstName, p.lastName, h) FROM Person p join p.house h`

Comment: Thanks. i was able to get that value. But is it possible to get the House object in its entirety and have that mapped to the DTO? So my Person object will need to be mapped manually due to Object[], but the House is returned in its entirety?

Comment: I tried: <code>SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, h FROM Person p join p.house h</code>  it didnt give me error but it returns null... can you help?